# AZURE DataSync troubles

Tags: azure, azure-data-sync

After refresh Schema of Hub dataBase I can not select tables to synchronize because the list of tables found does not show any check box next to can select them

Any error but any checkbox

Any idea please?[image]

Answer (score 0):

@kintela have you tried hovering over the table names. It should appear once you hover over the table name. As shown in the screenshot below. Also, if you want to select all the column columns click on Refresh Schema, it will select all the columns.

[image]

1. On the Tables page, select a database from the list of sync group members and select Refresh schema.
2. From the list, select the tables you want to sync. By default, all columns are selected, so disable the checkbox for the columns you don't want to sync. Be sure to leave the primary key column selected.
3. Select Save.

Reference Doc : [Configure Sync Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync#configure-sync-group)

Hope this helps. Please let us know if you are still facing this issue.